# iphone 5c pictures automatically synched to my home pc computer photo gallery

Tags: windows, iphone, photos, windows-photo-gallery

my college students iphone 5c pictures are being sent to my home pc's photo gallery without the owners knowledge. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Why are your students phones synced to your iTunes account?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have icloud backup setup on that iphone and on your home computer.  Assuming you mean the pictures are being synced while they're away at college.

It actually may be the photostream service apple offers.  You should be able to figure out how to have the student disable it using this info:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4486